# Java/ search in list with some variables

Tags: java, list

I have a linked list with object person.

```
Class person{
   int age;
   String name;
   String address
}
```

Now, I want to check if object is contained in the list. But my problem, is that only some fields are relevant. For example, I want to check if the person: tony, age 18 is contained in the list.

Are list support it? If not, which data structure  support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use a simple loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    Person p = list.get(i);
    if (p.name.equals("Tony") && p.age == 18) {
        //p is the person you were looking for
        //do whatever you wanted to do with p
        //if you don't want to include duplicate "Tonies" then add a break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can put your persons in a `List<Person>` and iterate over it:

```
for(Person p : personList){
    if ("tony".equals(p.name) && p.age == 18){
        //match - do some stuff
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

List has method `contains(obj)` it compares `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`

So if you override `equals` method in your Person class, and you could do `list.contains(obj)` it returns you true/false directly.

Comment: The problem with this is that then everywhere you use the Person object they will be considered equal if they have the same name and age and it will disregard the address, so Tony age 18 in San Francisco will be considered equal to Tony age 18 in Chicago, which probably isn't right in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can check like this

```
ArrayList<Person> persons=new ArrayList<Person>();
```

To check persons

do like this

```
for(Person p : persons)
{
 if (p.name.equals("Tony") && p.age == 18)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This class can be mapped to a table at databse and you want to execute a select * from person where age > 18.

There are 2 cases to do it: on is without index: the databse will read all values and it will do a compare to age field value, the same is with list: parse the list elements and you will find for sure, but this is the slowest method.

Other one is an optimisation for search: add an index to database to relevant fields.
In list you can have other data collection to speed up searching.

For example: LinkedHashSet> `indexedByAge` just ask it who is 18 or before 18 an you will get a series of ArrayList which need to merge to one with addAll() method.

Answer (score 1):

A bit messy, but you could **override the `equals` method** as follows:

```
class Person
{
   int age;
   String name;
   String address;

   Person(int a, String n, String ad) { age = a; name = n; address = ad; };
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o)
   {
      Person p = (Person)o;
      if (p.age != -1 && age != -1 && p.age != age)
         return false;
      if (p.name != null && name != null && !p.name.equals(name))
         return false;
      if (p.address != null && address != null && !p.address.equals(address))
         return false;
      return true;
   }
}
```

I'm assuming `-1` and `null` are uninitialized values.

**Usage:**

```
ArrayList<Person> arr = new ArrayList<Person>();
arr.add(new Person(18,"tony","here"));
System.out.println(arr.contains(new Person(18,"tony",null))); // prints true
```